# How to disable auto login in Meteor login with Facebook?

Tags: meteor, facebook-login

I am trying to setup a user authentication system using accounts-facebook in a Meteor Project. It seems to working properly. The only issue is after successfully logging out the user, it automatically login the user when I click the login button. I want the user to always type in their credentials after logging out.

Here is my template.login.events if it is even relevant to the problem

```
Template.login.events({
'click #facebook-login': function(event) {
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login failed");
        }else{
          Router.go('coupon')
        }
    });
},

'click #logout': function(event) {
    Meteor.logout(function(err){
        if (err) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("Logout failed");
        }else{
          Router.go('home');
        }
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. It's based on how Facebook works.

If the user logs out of Facebook, the user will have to enter their details again to log into your account, but if they're logged into Facebook already and have given your app permissions, they'll be logged in without any questions.